# pendingIntent Don't call OnNewIntent()

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-pendingintent, gcmlistenerservice, onnewintent

I receive message in my gcmlistener service and when app is in background , I receive notification but when i tap on it my intent doesn't call OnNewIntent in my main activity . Here is details what I've done

```
public class MyGcmPushReceiver extends GcmListenerService {

private static final String TAG = MyGcmPushReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle bundle) {
    String title = bundle.getString("title");
    String message = bundle.getString("message");
    String image = bundle.getString("image");
    String timestamp = bundle.getString("timestamp");
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + from);
    Log.e(TAG, "Title: " + title);
    Log.e(TAG, "message: " + message);
    Log.e(TAG, "image: " + image);
    Log.e(TAG, "timestamp: " + timestamp);   

    if (!NotificationUtils.isAppIsInBackground(getApplicationContext())) {

       .
       .

    } else {

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setAction(Config.PUSH_NOTIFICATION);
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        pushNotification.putExtra("PushReceive","PushReceive");
        pushNotification.putExtra("message", message);
        pushNotification.putExtra("title", title);
        pushNotification.putExtra("timestamp",timestamp);



        showNotificationMessage(getApplicationContext(), title, message, timestamp, resultIntent);



    }
}

/**
 * Showing notification with text only
 */
private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, String timeStamp, Intent intent) {
    notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);
    notificationUtils.showNotificationMessage(title, message, timeStamp, intent);

}
}
```

**NotificationUtils.class**

```
 public void showNotificationMessage(final String title, final String  message, final String timeStamp, Intent intent, String imageUrl) {
    // Check for empty push message
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(message))
        return;


    // notification icon
    final int icon = R.mipmap.ic_launcher;

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    int requestID = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    final PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    mContext,
                    requestID,
                    intent,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            );


    final NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            mContext);

    final Uri alarmSound = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE
            + "://" + mContext.getPackageName() + "/raw/notification");

    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(imageUrl)) {

       .
       .
       .
    } else {
        showSmallNotification(mBuilder, icon, title, message, timeStamp, resultPendingIntent, alarmSound);
        playNotificationSound();
    }
}


private void showSmallNotification(NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder, int icon, String title, String message, String timeStamp, PendingIntent resultPendingIntent, Uri alarmSound) {

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle = new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

    if (Config.appendNotificationMessages) {
        // store the notification in shared pref first
        MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().addNotification(message);

        // get the notifications from shared preferences
        String oldNotification = MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getNotifications();

        List<String> messages = Arrays.asList(oldNotification.split("\\|"));

        for (int i = messages.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            inboxStyle.addLine(messages.get(i));
        }
    } else {
        inboxStyle.addLine(message);
    }



    Notification notification;
    notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setSound(alarmSound)
            .setStyle(inboxStyle)
            .setWhen(getTimeMilliSec(timeStamp))
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
            .setContentText(message)
            .build();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(Config.NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="hdiz.designnotification" >
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />


<permission
    android:name="hdiz.designnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="hdiz.designnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:name=".MyApplication"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.DesignDemo">
    <activity
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
       >

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NotifDetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION" />
            <category android:name="hdiz.designnotification" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="gcm.MyGcmPushReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>


    <service
        android:name="gcm.MyInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="gcm.GcmIntentService"
        android:exported="false"></service>
</application>
```